# Regex with only: numbers, letters and accents

Tags: php, regex, replace, diacritics

I need to filter string to return only "numbers, letters and letters with accents" using **PHP**.

I've tried many different regex and I could not.

The closest I got was:

```
$string = 'Você está bem? 123 # ! @ ...';
echo preg_replace('/[^\w\s+$]/', '_', $string);

// Return: Voc__ est__ bem_ 123 _ _ _ ___
// But I need to return: Você_está_bem_123 _ _ _ ___
```

Can someone help me? I tried to solve it out for hours, even looking for other questions here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `/u` modifier:

```
$string = 'Você está bem? 123 # ! @ ...';
echo preg_replace('/[^\w\s+$]/u', '_', $string);
                              ^
```

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/wjPxv8)

More about the `/u` modifier in SO regex documentation:

> **Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8.**

Comment: Just FYI: if your input also contains diacritics as separate symbols (you need to add `\p{M}` to the character class: `/[^\w\p{M}\s+$]/u` as `/\w/u` only matches `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`

Comment: It's work, thank you! But, I need use "utf8_decode" and so not work: https://ideone.com/IagsYU

Comment: You should run the regex on the Unicode string *before* passing it to the `utf8_decode`.

Comment: I found that do not need the "utf8_decode()", then removed it. What was missing was a "charset = utf-8". Thank you!